# pgrid - fixed column width of table

Tags: jquery

I am using [Pines Grid](http://pinesframework.org/pgrid/) for my Web Project.

Is there any way using i can set column width fixed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this property to pgrid.css

```
white-space:nowrap;
```